# Android Studio: Boolean function crashes my app

Tags: java, android, crash, boolean

Im trying to learn how to use android studio, im not unfamiliar with java though.
I tried making a boolean and if it is true, a text changes to "ON", otherwise it will change to "OFF"
My app just crashes when im using USB-Debugging though.

Code:
MainActivity.java

```
    package com.leuchtstein.flashlight;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public boolean stat = false;
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)   ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


 public void triggerlight(View view) {

 if (stat == false) {


    text.setText("ON");
    stat = true;


} else {


    text.setText("OFF");
    stat = false;


  }



  }


 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout               
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.leuchtstein.flashlight.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/desc_textview"
          android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="triggerlight"
    android:text="Turn on/off"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.387" />
```

Well, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is triggerlight called?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)   ;` move it inside oncreate after setContentView

Answer (score 2):

Don't call

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)   ;
```

in initialisation, rather call it in `onCreate()` method.

This is because Android first initializes the script, and calls onCreate only when `setContentView()` has been called and it has set up the button, &c. Thus `findViewById(int id)` can't find anything yet.

Put

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

in `onCreate()` and put

```
TextView text;
```

in initialisation instead.

Comment: It also might be good to mention that `findViewById` needs to be called *after* the call to `setContentView`.

Comment: Great! I made this mistake too when I learnt it :) If it's helpful, click the 'accept answer' button on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean stat = false;
    TextView text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the logcat or any other any ifo, but one thing I can see here that could go wrong is this :

`TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Change your code to look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)   
}
```

So the difference is, you assign a value to your `TextView` using `findViewById`, after you have have called `setContentView()`.
All view assignments should be only done after `setContentView()`is called in activities because that is where you set your root view and when you call `findViewById()`, the system looks up a view with an id in the root view.